# ACCESS VBA LISTBOX addressing

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I wanted to simply move the selected row up and down the list box.
I have code which works - but I dont understand why!
There is clearly a reference difference btween Selected and ListIndex.  I would be grateful if someone could point out the(no doubt elementary) point I am overlooking

```
Private Sub INPUT_AfterUpdate()

  If Me.INPUT = "up" Then Call go_up
  If Me.INPUT = "down" Then Call go_down

  Me.show = me.List59.Column(1)
  Me.INPUT = ""

End Sub

Private Sub go_up()

  Temp_var = Me.List59.ListIndex
  '!!!!!! why  do I not need to change Temp_var !!!
  me.List59.Selected(Temp_var) = True
End Sub

Private Sub go_down()
  Temp_var = Me.List59.ListIndex
  Temp_var = Temp_var + 2 '!!!!!! why 2 !!!

  me.List59.Selected(a) = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> why 2?

Because *ListIndex* starts with 0 while *Selected* starts with 1.

So +1/-1 plus 1 -> +2/0.

And the last line should read:

```
Me.List59.Selected(Temp_var) = True
```

Comment: The last line correction is valid - I simplified the example and overlooked that change . I knew the answer was simple !!!